# How to reference VirtualTree records from one VT to another VT in C++Builder?

Tags: c++builder, virtualtreeview, c++builder-xe5

Could someone help me with using VirtualTree in C++Builder?

I have `VT1` with records in it:

[image]

And `VT2` with records in it:

[image]

I copy values from `VT1` to `VT2`:

```
void __fastcall TForm3::CopyItemsFromVT1ToVT2(TVirtualStringTree *VT_List, PVirtualNode NodeList, TVirtualStringTree *VT_Tree, PVirtualNode NodeTree) {
   ((PTreeData)VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree))->Id=((TForm1::PTreeData)VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList))->Id;
   ((PTreeData)VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree))->Type=((TForm1::PTreeData)VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList))->Type;
   ((PTreeData)VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree))->Date=((TForm1::PTreeData)VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList))->Date;
   ((PTreeData)VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree))->Time=((TForm1::PTreeData)VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList))->Time;
   ((PTreeData)VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree))->Char_Code=((TForm1::PTreeData)VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList))->Char_Code;
   ((PTreeData)VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree))->Number_Code=((TForm1::PTreeData)VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList))->Number_Code;
   ((PTreeData)VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree))->Message=((TForm1::PTreeData)VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList))->Message;
}
```

How can I reference records from `VT1` to `VT2` instead?  Is this correct?

```
((PTreeData)VT2->GetNodeData(ParentNodeTarget)) = ((PTreeData)VT1->GetNodeData(ParentNodeSource))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying individual fields manually, you can let the compiler do it for you, assuming `TreeData` is a `struct` or `class` with an `operator=` implemented (particular a default one generated by the compiler), eg:

```
struct TreeData
{
    ...
};
typedef TreeData *PTreeData;

...

VT1->NodeDataSize = sizeof(TreeData);
VT2->NodeDataSize = sizeof(TreeData);

...

void __fastcall TForm3::CopyItemsFromVT1ToVT2(TVirtualStringTree *VT_List, PVirtualNode NodeList, TVirtualStringTree *VT_Tree, PVirtualNode NodeTree)
{
    *static_cast<PTreeData>(VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree)) = *static_cast<PTreeData>(VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList));
}
```

But, if you want `VT2` nodes to simply point at the same data as `VT1` nodes, without making copies, then you need to allocate the `TreeData` instances outside of any nodes, and then just store `TreeData*` pointers inside of the nodes, eg:

```
struct TreeData
{
    ...
};
typedef TreeData *PTreeData, **PPTreeData;

...

VT1->NodeDataSize = sizeof(PTreeData);
VT2->NodeDataSize = sizeof(PTreeData);

...

PTreeData data = new TreeData;
// initialize data as needed ...
*static_cast<PPTreeData>(VT1->GetNodeData(SomeNode)) = data;

...

// OnFreeNode event handler for VT1...
void __fastcall TForm3::VT1FreeNode(TBaseVirtualTree *Sender, PVirtualNode Node)
{
    delete *static_cast<PPTreeData>(Sender->GetNodeData(Node));
}

...

void __fastcall TForm3::CopyItemsFromVT1ToVT2(TVirtualStringTree *VT_List, PVirtualNode NodeList, TVirtualStringTree *VT_Tree, PVirtualNode NodeTree)
{
    *static_cast<PPTreeData>(VT_Tree->GetNodeData(NodeTree)) = *static_cast<PPTreeData>(VT_List->GetNodeData(NodeList));
}
```

Comment: Thank's Remy second case is best: less memory and best performance i assume :) question: PTreeData data = new TreeData;  will be  delete OnFreeNode event handler for VT1 ???